# Condition sorting in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

We have a situation where we want to sort by `total- count`

for ex : `sort=Total_ix - count_ix`

In addition, we want to sort by date in case there is a tie in 2 numbers while sorting.

Is it possible to do this in Solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Solr allows to sort results by the output of a function, so you can use `sub()` to substract *count* from *total*. It also supports multiple sort ordering and you can provide a list of comma-separated sort criteria.

> A sort ordering must include a field name (or score as a pseudo
>   field), followed by whitespace (escaped as + or %20 in URL strings),
>   followed by a sort direction.

In your situation, you can do something like :

```
sort=sub(Total_ix, count_ix) desc, date desc
```

cf. [The sort parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter), [Function Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries)

Comment: Is it ok to write complex sort like: `sort=sub(sum(count_ix, count_ix),Total_ix)`. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's ok, but you must specify a sort direction (ascending or descending), you can also use `mul()` : `sort=sub(mul(count_ix, 2), Total_ix) asc`

Comment: Would you mind answering this too? :) `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968739/condition-filtering-by-count-in-solr`